# Node.js Cannot read property 'toJsonWith' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dictionary, nestjs

I'm trying to return icons, as a result, to produce them on the page

The following code below `map` all the results that I'm trying to return to the page.

```
const icons = await Icon.find({ _id: { $in: ids } }).select({ ...options.select, ...options.additional })
    const results = ids
      .map(id => {
        const iconsGroup = icons.find(icon => icon.id === id)
        if (query.hasPublishingError) {
          iconsGroup.icons = iconsGroup.icons.filter(el => (el.errorsData.length > 0 && el.status === 'draft'))
        }
        return iconsGroup
      })
      .map(i => i.toJsonWith(options.select))

await postProcess(results)

    return {
      docs: results,
      limit: response.limit,
      page: response.page,
      pages: response.pages,
      total: response.total
    }
```

When I'm making a `GET` request, I'm getting an error such as:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJsonWith' of undefined\n`

The painful point is `.map(i => i.toJsonWith(options.select))`

By the way, for some reason, this function `toJsonWith` cannot be found as a declaration somewhere.
Please help me, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong here for 4 days.

Comment: cannot read property 'toJsonWith' of undefined means that in this case `i` is undefined, so maybe check if results is empty before mapping

Comment: And did you write the function `toJsonWith` by yourself? If not you may forgot to import it, but i didnt find any packages containing this function

Comment: @mrJQuery linter shows me that it is possible to call `toJsonWith()` from some object, I assume that there is no need to import it. And yeah, most likely there `i` is undefined, but I do not understand how to re-evaluate this expression to make it work correctly, also if `i` is undefined, why field `id` is **not undefined**

Comment: `i` is undefined, because your first map doesnt return anything. if would check if  `icons.find(icon => icon.id === id)` does return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an _id should always be unique so

```
const iconsGroup = icons.find(icon => icon.id === id)
```

should return an arrayObject with a maximum of one Element.

Then you check for publishing errors

```
if (query.hasPublishingError) {
      iconsGroup.icons = iconsGroup.icons.filter(el => (el.errorsData.length > 0 && el.status === 'draft'))
    }
```

And here it can happen that iconsGroup is an empty array.

Next you make a second map to use your magical toJsonWith (i also don't know what it does).

You can combine these two maps and iterate direclty over your icons instead of using a map on your ids (following code gives you an array of icons depending of query.hasPublishingError):

```
const results = icons.map(icon => {
if (query.hasPublishingError && icon.errorsData.length > 0 && icon.status === 'draft') {
    return icon.toJsonWith(options.select)
} else {
    return icon.toJsonWith(options.select)
}
})
```

Comment: toJsonWith is a function that was written before me, and I have to use it. I'll try this one and mark  the answer in case if it will work